# Facing a problem while using particle systems

Tags: materials, particles

I was making some roof tiles with particle system.In the viewport it seemed ok but when i rendereed it the result was not expected.I attach the node setup i used for the roof tile particle,the result i expected was to have one colour for each tile from the two colours,But something iunespected happended.

[image]

Comment: Hello, it looks strange to me too. Would you please share your particle settings?

Comment: It seems like mesh geometry is intersecting with each other. Do you by any chance have child particles enabled and set a particle value higher than the viewport for the final render?